# Is making each day a component in a reactjs calender bad?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create a full page calender (All months are displayed one after the another in a single page). I am getting confused as to how to approach this, what I want to know is if making each day a component then a month component and the whole thing in a container bad? This code will go into production so I want good performance.

I also have to display some number(price for each date) with each date if that influences the decision.

I am looking to create a product that will look similar to [React-Infinite-Calender](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-calendar) but each day will also have a pricing detail as mentioned before.

Also is there a better way to approach this than the one I mentioned?

Comment: you can always render `n-1` / `n` / `n+1` months per view. meaning, if you are looking at "April" you can render the days for `March` / `April` / `May` so you can support transitions, when the user navigates to  `May` you will render `April` / `May` / `June`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that modularizing your application is a bad idea or will affect your applications performance.

Splitting up an application in several `components` is what makes `React` this performant in the first place.

In your case it might be a good idea to determine if you need a component that is `stateful` or `functional`. From what you are presenting as your scenario I would go with an approach where the month (as one `component`) holds the state and then renders several `functional components` (as days) with the data (including the price tag you mentioned) passed to it via `props`.

There are several good ressources to be found online where you can read about structuring/modularizing your application with `React components`.

One of them is this post about structuring `React` apps: [Structuring React apps](https://hackernoon.com/the-100-correct-way-to-structure-a-react-app-or-why-theres-no-such-thing-3ede534ef1ed)

Answer (score 1):

React is a component-based framework, so abstracting every item into separate component is the proper way. It allows you to have all the logic responsible for various elements incapsulated.

When creating your app, just remember to use `map` to generate the months and days inside. Doing to will quickly prove that your idea is correct.

Also, remember about passing props to children and stateless components, this will greatly improve your workflow and performance. Keep in mind though, that avoiding `state` can be harmful. Hoisting your logic up a few components will be a much bigger hit on your performance that using `state`.

Last, but not least, if you'll run into a problem with communication of components far from each other, try state management tools, like Redux.